# Hundreds of sessions queued in suspended state

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, waits

We experience hundreds of sessions going in suspended state on rare occasions.
When it happens there is no increase in terms of resource usage - CPU or memory. Rather there is a small amount of decrease 5-10% on CPU.
There is no single error on the SQL log.
I know this will be a blind question but what might be causing this? Any suggestions to check in SQL Server like plan cache etc..?

Comment: What are they waiting on? Sounds like a blocking chain.

Comment: What does `sp_WhoIsActive` say? Or, at least, what is `Activity Monitor` telling about wait types?

Comment: There should be a spid that must have been blocking another one and so on . Find that parent blocking spid and check what is it waiting for. That should give you an idea

Comment: Foremost wait type is PageLatch_Up: 400 minutes of waiting over 1 minute!
Second wait type is PageLatch_Sh: 166 minutes of waiting over 1 minute

Comment: My monitoring tool confirms there were no blocking sessions.

Comment: Do you have any scheduled tasks through the Agent that performs any data modifications? This is not an I/O problem *per se*, but may be related to tempdb contention.

Comment: There are multiple agent jobs inserting into table variables with all their wait type Pagelatch_Up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was tempdb contention. Adding more tempdb data files and enabling trace flag 1118 solved the issue.